# Is it possible to process multiple spreadsheets in parallel?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, parallel-processing

We have a spreadsheet in Google Spreadsheet, where each line contains a link to another spreadsheet, like this :

[image]

I inherited a "Google Apps Script" script which parses this first spreadsheet, then sequentially open each pointed spreadsheet (there's hundreds of them) with the openById method of the SpreadSheetApp class, gather some values from each spreadsheet and put them in another spreadsheet.
This is obviously tremendously slow, so much that the script has to manage the continuationToken and to reinject it in itself to be able to complete the whole process.
I'm trying to optimize the whole thing.
I've read :

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices
- https://ramblings.mcpher.com/orchestration-of-apps-scripts-parallel-threads-and-defeating-quotas/ , https://github.com/brucemcpherson/gasThreader
  and also investigated triggers, `urlFetchAll`, and so on.

I don't see how i can avoid opening each spreadsheet one by one, and thus "minimize calls to other services" (@best practices).

There's probably a more efficient way, in terms of processing time.

I couldn't find in the Gas api something like C#'s Parallel.ForEach.
Any pointers ?
Should I completely rework the whole logic ?

Comment: Please define "better and simple way" (add the criteria of acceptance) otherwise the question is primarily opinion based (in other words, off-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the question

> I don't see how i can avoid opening each spreadsheet one by one, and thus "minimize calls to other services" (@best practices).

I don't think that there is a way to do that in Google Apps Script. You could try using client side code to open some of the spreadsheets  in parallel as is suggested by Bruce Mcpherson (the author of one of the links included in the question). AFAIK it's not possible to open hundreds of spreadsheets at the same time by a single account due to Google Apps Script quotas.

> I couldn't find in the Gas api something like C#'s Parallel.ForEach. Any pointers ?

Depending on the operations that you need to do it might be helpful to use the [Advanced Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/sheets) and `batchUpdate` (see [this example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/sheets#write_values_to_multiple_ranges))

> Should I completely rework the whole logic ?

The question hasn't enough details but considering that you have inherited the script and you decide to use the Advanced Spreadsheet Service it's very likely that you should be ending reworking the whole logic or even changing "the system" (maybe you should not use Google Apps Script / Google Sheets for this).